# While moving files in Finder, how to prevent the files from hiding the target folder?

Tags: finder

When you want to move a group of files in Finder in column mode, you first select the group, then drag the group to a target folder. The problem is that the files hide the target folder, and in column mode, you have to put the mouse cursor over the file name. Sometimes, the files fade a little, get out of the way, and a red label with the total number of files is displayed. I don't know when this happens, but this solves the problem, because nothing is displayed near the cursor. Also, sometimes the files are not moved away from the cursor, but there is still a red label displaying the number of files.

Is there a way to force the dragged files to be always displayed in a compact, faded way, with the red label indicating the number of elements being moved ? If it is not possible, when does this happen exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

After selecting the group of files. Position your cursor (not the item in column) inside the column area where your target folder is located. Wait for a few seconds for the list of selected items to fade away right to the mouse cursor.

Instead of using column view, I recommend [DragonDrop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dragondrop/id499148234?mt=12&uo=4) to make moving files between folders easier.

Comment: Wait where, doing what ?

Comment: I‘ve made some change. You should be able to repeat the fade away behavior if you position your cursor including selected files within blank area in the column view.

Comment: Doesn't work when the files and the target folder are in the same folder. But apparently if you can trick Finder in doing this by dragging the files over the parent column folder (if any), and drag it  back on the target folder. Even like this it's not really reliable. I think it's most probably a bug in Finder.